# Algorithm to find neuralgic point2 in a large graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Assume i have a large arbitrary graph of connected vertices like the following. Assume these are network connections. Some connections (colored in red) are much more serve to damage then others. If two red connections fail, many points have no more connection to members of the remaining island.

How can find these neuralgic connections?

Is there a existing algorithm for that?

[image: graph sample]

Comment: Maybe adapt a min-cut algorithm?

Comment: Here's a wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_cut. The idea is that weighing the edges evenly, it looks like your red edges would be the min cut.

Comment: Is there ever a situation where black connections make a circuit around the red connections?

Comment: I just made the 3 lines red for better explanation. Connections have no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You are wondering about [Edge Connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph).  In your case you seem to only care about the graph being 2-edge-connected, there might be specific algorithms for this case but I'm not sure.  Here is a simple algorithm that I think should work:

```
For all edges, E, in your graph, G:
  Remove E from G.
  Find any path, P, from src(E) to dst(E).
  Remove all edges in P from G.
  Find a path from src(E) to dst(E),
    if none exists then E is one of your important edges.
```

This is not fast, though, it takes O(E*(E+V)), if your graph is planar then this isn't too bad, since O(E) == O(V), and so it will take time O(V^2).  If your graph is much more connected then this could be as bad as O(V^4), which might be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, I would say that you need to look at flow networks : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network.